# Show loading spinner while removing/adding large set of table rows

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a country select dropdown and a large data table of about 4k rows/records. When users select a country, a function is called to [1] remove what's currently there then [2] display records related to the selected country. I noticed the action of removing / adding records can take a few seconds and want to show a loading spinner, but it doesn't seem to work. When picking a country from the dropdown, things look like standing still for a few seconds, then the dropdown updates with the selected country, then new data show. My spinner is not showing. How to make this work?

**** EDIT: I added the load data function. Note that there're more data point (more table cells in a row) than just country and company.

```
<select id="ct_select" onchange="filterCountry()">...</select>

<div id="loader"><img src="/images/ui/icon_loading.gif" /></div>

<table id="part_list">
<tbody id="part_list_body">
... thousand of rows depending on what country is selected
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
function filterCountry(){
  $('#loader img').show(); //show loading spinner
  $('#part_list_body').remove();
  $('#part_list').append($('<tbody id="part_list_body">'));
  loadSelectCountry($xmldata);
  $('#loader img').hide();
}
```

```
function loadSelectCountry(xml){
  $xmldata = xml;

  var countryArr = [];
  var companyArr = [];
  ...
  $(xml).find("ct:contains('"+$country+"')").parent().each(function(){
  var country = $(this).find('ct').text();
  var company = $(this).find('co').text(); 
  var industry = $(this).find('ind').text();
 
  countryArr.push(country);
  companyArr.push(company);
  ...
  
  })
    
  $.each(companyArr, function(index) {
  $("#part_list_body").append('<tr class="datarow"><td>' + this + '</td><td>'+companyArr[index] + '</td></tr>');    
  });
      
  $('#part_list').trigger('update');
   
}
```

Comment: And where is your loader element? What styles do you use in there? Have you tried to display it without the script (default visible)?

Comment: I've just edited the question to add the loader element - missed it at first. I have an ajax call to load and display the xml data initially and the loader works ok with that call.

Comment: are you adding the rows in loop? or are you composing the element then adding the whole thing? adding the rows one by one probably not a good idea

Comment: I've added the rows with loop using each(). I load data from xml first, then my function is to loop through the xml to find data associated with the country name, then display them.

Comment: we need to see the whole code that adds the rows. instead of showing "..." otherwise how can we determine why it is slow?

Comment: without looking at the code is hard to tell. but i am guessing you add the rows one by one... what i would do is construct the whole outer html or object and then replace the whole object.  In otherwords once you have the whole body composed then replace it in one shot

Comment: I've added the core stuff in my load function. It's not the whole, but I hope it's enough. I don't mind things a bit slow (a few seconds to load), I'd like to add the spinner to let people know something is coming instead of the still/frozen screen

Comment: FYI - The xml itself has more than 10k rows. Depending  on the country, the result to display can be anywhere from 100 to 4k rows. I understand handling all this with xml and client side is not good, but I'm just doing with what's available to use.